# EXTRACT() Hour in 24 Hour format

Tags: oracle

I have something like below-

```
EXTRACT(HOUR from CAST(to_char(tran_datetime,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP))
```

`tran_datetime` is `DATE` type. This gives error for some rows saying `HOUR must be between 1 and 12`, so I understand that it cannot handle Hour in a `24 Hour` format (or military time). The below works (obviously)-

```
EXTRACT(HOUR from CAST(to_char(tran_datetime,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP))
```

or

```
EXTRACT(HOUR from CAST(tran_datetime AS TIMESTAMP))  --12 Hr format by default
```

Is there a way to use `EXTRACT()` to get the `HOUR` in 24 Hour format i.e. 15 for 3 PM, 13 for 1 PM etc.

Please Note- `to_char(tran_datetime,'HH24')` is a very obvious option, but I am looking to use `EXTRACT()` function specifically.

Comment: I do not have any problem extracting HH24 on an Oracle 11g Express - select extract(hour from cast(sysdate+0.5 as timestamp)) as extract_hour, to_char(sysdate+0.5, 'HH24:MM') from dual == 21 and 21:10 respectfully

Comment: What is the difference betweeen first piece of code and the second(which you say it works)? Seems to be the same code.

Comment: @FlorinGhita sorry that was a copy-paste mistake.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is not with `extract`, which can certainly handle 'military time'. It looks like you have a default timestamp format which has `HH` instead of `HH24`; or at least that's the only way I can see to recreate this:

```
SQL> select value from nls_session_parameters
  2  where parameter = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT';

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF

SQL> select extract(hour from cast(to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  2  as timestamp)) from dual;

EXTRACT(HOURFROMCAST(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYYHH24:MI:SS')ASTIMESTAMP))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                        15

alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> select extract(hour from cast(to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  2  as timestamp)) from dual;

select extract(hour from cast(to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as timestamp)) from dual
                              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12
```

So the simple 'fix' is to set the format to something that does recognise 24-hours:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> select extract(hour from cast(to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  2  as timestamp)) from dual;

EXTRACT(HOURFROMCAST(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYYHH24:MI:SS')ASTIMESTAMP))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                        15
```

Although you don't need the `to_char` at all:

```
SQL> select extract(hour from cast(sysdate as timestamp)) from dual;

EXTRACT(HOURFROMCAST(SYSDATEASTIMESTAMP))
-----------------------------------------
                                       15
```

Comment: This `select extract(hour from CAST(sysdate+0.5 AS TIMESTAMP)) hr from dual;` returns me `22` even when my NLS Parameter is set to `HH` format. So I guess I don't need to set NLS to `HH24`.

Comment: @Annjawn - no, that's only needed if you have the implicit conversion to timestamp format, because  of the `varchar` returned by the `to_char()`. If you leave it as a `date` then you avoid the implicit conversion, so the NLS parameter isn't referred to.

Answer (score 20):

```
select to_char(tran_datetime,'HH24') from test;

TO_CHAR(tran_datetime,'HH24')
------------------
16
```

Comment: Just what at looking for, very clean solution

Comment: I like it, the only con is that it's a CHAR now so if you want to compute something you will need to cast. just an observation.

Comment: Oracle will cast it for you : select to_char(tran_datetime,'HH24')*2 from test; returns 32

Answer (score 3):

simple and easier solution:

```
select extract(hour from systimestamp) from dual;

EXTRACT(HOURFROMSYSTIMESTAMP)
-----------------------------
                           16
```

Comment: Since the question was about DATE you would need some conversion, e.g. a cast:
select extract(hour from cast(sysdate as timestamp)) from dual;