# Datetime between specific hour in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, time

I have a column with the format of datetime: TRANDATE

In the query, there is a condition of startdate and enddate that shows all the transactions that have occurred between those dates of the column TRANDATE.

I want to add a condition of TIME in hour. So that it should return all the transactions that have occured between the starttime and endtime hour of TRANDATE.

The query would have 4 parameters:
TRANDATE between startdate and enddate
TRANDATE between starthour (number) and endhour (number)

How do I do the time (hour) part ?

Comment: Can you please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916611/extract-hour-in-24-hour-format and see this resolves?

Comment: PLEASE show sample table data and expected output.

Comment: There is no 'datetime' data type is Oracle? Do you mean DATE or TIMESTAMP?

Answer (score 3):

You can add a condition on hour between HOUR_START and HOUR_END this way:

```
... AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TRANDATE) BETWEEN HOUR_START AND HOUR_END ...
```