# Can i get the 2 hour digits in Oracle Business Intelligence using HOUR()?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, business-intelligence, obiee

I'm trying to get the hour from a `timestamp` column, i use the `HOUR()` funtion and im available to get it but i need to get the 2 digit hour.

This is what i already try:

```
          HOUR("Column.Name")
```

This is what i get in my output, do not worry about the minutes:

[image: This is what i get in my output, do not worry about the minutes]

For example in my output i have `7:00` and `9:30`, after using the `HOUR` function i would like to get `07` and `09` instead of `7` and `9`.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: See Alex Poole's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916611/extract-hour-in-24-hour-format

Comment: Don't work, when i have something like 07:12:43 i still got 7 instead of 07

Answer (score 0):

`select LPAD(extract(hour from SYSTIMESTAMP),2,'0') from dual;`

You can use the Oracle extract functionality which extracts hour from a TIMESTAMP field.

Note : It does not work with DATE datatype only TIMESTAMP should be an input parameter

Oracle Reference : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm#SQLRF00639

Comment: Don't work, when i have something like 07:12:43 i still got 7 instead of 07

Comment: You need to use LPAD functionality to achieve this