# C# windows form shows 0 in datagridview where for data grouped by hour, but SQL developer shows the correct results

Tags: c#, oracle, winforms, datagridview

I have a query in Oracle to display number of transactions by hour, then the last column displays the sum for all hours. The query works fine in SQL developer. 
However, when I try to display the results in a datagridview of my windows form application, I get 0 for all the hour data. I do however get the final total.

This is the first time I have had trouble using the date picker and displaying data in the datagridview.

Here is a screenshot of the results in SQL developer (I realize the total column does not equal the total of the columns shown. The screen shot does not show all columns.)

[image]

And here is the screenshot of the same data in window forms.

[image]

This is what I believe is the relevant SQL code. Please forgive me if it is too much.

```
SELECT
 user_name,
 SUM(CASE
     WHEN substr(hr,11) = '19:00:00' THEN t
     ELSE 0
 END) AS eight_pm,
 SUM(CASE
     WHEN substr(hr,11) = '20:00:00' THEN t
     ELSE 0
 END) AS nine_pm,
 SUM(CASE
     WHEN substr(hr,11) = '21:00:00' THEN t
     ELSE 0
 END) AS ten_pm,
 SUM(CASE
     WHEN substr(hr,11) = '22:00:00' THEN t
     ELSE 0
 END) AS eleven_pm,
 SUM(t) total
 FROM
 (
     SELECT
         user_name,
         COUNT(*) t,
         TO_CHAR(trunc(last_update_date,'HH24') ) AS hr
     FROM
         cte
     GROUP BY
         user_name,
         TO_CHAR(trunc(last_update_date,'HH24') )
 )
 GROUP BY
 user_name
 ORDER BY
 user_name
```

I am not doing anything with the date picker other that using it as a parameter to query the data. I can show the custom format or some of the C# code if necessary.

Please note, I will not be able to test any solutions until tomorrow morning.
Thank you for your time.

**Update**
Adding code for populating datagridview:

```
 private void btnSecondShiftStats_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var start = startDatePicker.Value;
        var end = endDatePicker.Value;
        string name = tbName.Text;

        dvgSecondShiftStats.DataSource = _secondShiftStatsData.GetStats(start, end, name);
    }
```

The GetStats method:

```
   public List<SecondShiftStats> GetStats(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, string uName)
    {
        var statList = new List<SecondShiftStats>();
        var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SecondShiftStatsConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conString))
        {
            string sql = @"WITH loaded AS (
                                             SELECT...";

            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":start_time", OracleDbType.Date)).Value = fromDate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":end_time", OracleDbType.Date)).Value = toDate;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("name", uName);

                con.Open();
                using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var stats = new SecondShiftStats();
                        stats.USER_NAME = reader["USER_NAME"].ToString();
                        stats.THREE_PM = Convert.ToInt32(reader["THREE_PM"]);
                        stats.FOUR_PM = Convert.ToInt32(reader["FOUR_PM"]);
                        stats.FIVE_PM = Convert.ToInt32(reader["FIVE_PM"]);
                        stats.SIX_PM = Convert.ToInt32(reader["SIX_PM"]);
                        stats.SEVEN_PM = Convert.ToInt32(reader["SEVEN_PM"]);
                        stats.EIGHT_PM = Convert.ToInt32(reader["EIGHT_PM"]);
                        stats.NINE_PM = Convert.ToInt32(reader["NINE_PM"]);
                        stats.TEN_PM = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TEN_PM"]);
                        stats.ELEVEN_PM = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ELEVEN_PM"]);
                        stats.TOTAL = Convert.ToInt32(reader["TOTAL"]);

                        statList.Add(stats);
                    }
                }

            } 

        }
        return statList;
    }
```

Comment: The SQL looks ok but can you show your code where you populate the data for the DataGridView control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out solution to this problem. I have another app showing the same query, but without the grouping. I saw a difference in the datetime format in sql developer vs the datagridview.

SQL Developer:

[image]

Datagridview:

[image]

And finally the format of the Datetimepicker:

[image]

I never changed the way the datgridview displays the date. I only customized the datetimepicker and used it as a parameter in the query. This appeared to be the issue.

So I changed the relevant column in the select statement to:

```
TO_CHAR(last_update_date, 'DD/MON/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')AS last_update_date.
```

Of course, I knew I would have to change my final select to:

```
select ...
case when substr(hr,11)...
```

to

```
select ...
case when substr(hr,13)...
```

Or so I thought.
I would get an ORA-01722: invalid-number message when I tried to run the query in SQL Developer.

I determined it was in the grouping statement again, and looked for other solutions to group by the hour. I tried using the accepted answer from this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916611/extract-hour-in-24-hour-format) , but received a message stating the hour number must be between 1 and 12, even though I have my format set to 'HH24'.

To fix this issue, I changed the final subquery to:

```
SELECT
 user_name,
 SUM(CASE
     WHEN hr = '19' THEN t
     ELSE 0
 END) AS eight_pm,
 SUM(CASE
     WHEN hr  = '20' THEN t
     ELSE 0
 END) AS nine_pm,
 SUM(CASE
     WHEN hr = '21' THEN t
     ELSE 0
 END) AS ten_pm,
 SUM(CASE
     WHEN hr = '22' THEN t
     ELSE 0
 END) AS eleven_pm,
 SUM(t) total
 FROM
 (
     SELECT
         user_name,
         COUNT(*) t,
         substr(last_update_date,13,2)as hr
     FROM
         cte
     GROUP BY
         user_name,
        substr(last_update_date,13,2)
 )
 group by
 user_name
 order by
 user_name
```

After making these changes, my applications displays the results I expect it to:

[image]